# Зачем запрещать переопределение виртуальных функций?

Tags: c++, функции, виртуальная-функция

Используя ключевое слово final мы можем запретить переопределение виртуальной функции в классах наследниках. Зачем тогда вообще делать функцию виртуальной?

Comment: Когда, например, вы описали всех типов врачей, которые могут выполнить хирургическую операцию, нужно запрещать это делать другим типам врачей(ужесточение ролей объектов)

Answer (score 3):

Делать функцию виртуальной в родителе, и сразу `final` - нет смысла, да.

Ее можно сделать `final` в потомке, который ее переопределеяет, чтобы уже следующий потомок ее не трогал.

Answer (score 2):

`final` имеет смысл использовать, чтобы

1. в любых классах: запретить дальнейшее наследование
2. в классах-наследниках: предоставить компилятору дополнительную возможность оптимизировать вызов виртуальной функции через указатель или ссылку на финальный класс-наследник